# streamreader exception URI formats are not supported

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am using `azure blob storage`. I stored an txt file in the storage, and now i am trying to read it through :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri); 
Blob containes the reference of the blob where txt file is stored.
```

But here i am getting the exception `(URI formats are not supported.)`. I think the `streamreader` does'nt support the URI formate. Can anybody please give me a better work arround for this ?

( i know one that we can use `DowmloadToFile` method of  `CloudBlob` to download the file and then create an address by using Server.MapPath and put that address instead of URI. But if there is any other better solution for this then please let me know )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [WebClient.OpenRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144209.aspx) or [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring) methods.

Your code will looks like something like that :

```
var wc = new WebClient();
using(var sourceStream = wc.OpenRead(Blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri)){
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream)){
         // Process
    }
}
```

Or if the file is small (text files are often small), :

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var fileContent = wc.DownloadString(Blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```